# Is there any way to transform a string according to text row above?

Tags: php, regex, for-loop, while-loop, do-while

I have a long array list that includes genus rows (start with capital letters like: ACHNANTHES) and species rows (start with capital letter first and a dot like: A.) i need to transform a little part, according to above text. Here below you can easily understand:

```
ACHNANTHES
A. brevipes
A. coarctata
A. cocconeiformis
A. gibberula
A. lacunarum 
A. lineariformis
A. longipes
A. nollii
A. parvula
A. petersenii
A. pyrenaicum
A. stolida
A. thermalis
A. trinodis
A. wellsiae
PLATESSA
P. conspicua
P. montana
P. salinarum
ACHNANTHIDIUM
A. affine
A. deflexum
A. exiguum
A. exile
A. lanceolatum
A. minutissimum
A. minutum
A. thermale
```

I want to transform it to this:

```
ACHNANTHES
Achantes brevipes
Achantes coarctata
Achantes cocconeiformis
Achantes gibberula
Achantes lacunarum
Achantes lineariformis
Achantes longipes
Achantes nollii
Achantes parvula
Achantes petersenii
Achantes pyrenaicum
Achantes stolida
Achantes thermalis
Achantes trinodis
Achantes wellsiae
PLATESSA
Platessa conspicua
Platessa montana
Platessa salinarum
ACHNANTHIDIUM
Achanthidium affine
Achanthidium deflexum
Achanthidium exiguum
Achanthidium exile
Achanthidium lanceolatum
```

Think i need to use while or foreach in PHP, but i don't know how to do it. Help please.

@mickmackmusa as you wanted here is a part of my array:

```
array (
  0 => 'ACHNANTHES Bory, Dict. Class. Hist. Nat. 1: 79 (1822). / SUCINCIĞI.',
  1 => 'A. brevipes C.Agardh, Syst. Alg.: 1 (1824). / Küçük sucıncığı.',
  2 => 'A. coarctata (Bréb. ex W.Sm.) Grunow, Syn. Diat. Belg.: expl. pl. XXVI: ş. 17 (1880). / Dar sucıncığı.',
  3 => 'A. cocconeiformis Mann, U.S. Nat. Mus., Bull. 6: 182 (1925). / Top sucıncığı.',
  4 => 'A. gibberula Grunow, Kongl. Svenska Vetensk.-Akad. Handl. 17(2): 121 (1880). / Kambur sucıncığı.',
  5 => 'A. lacunarum Hust., Bacillariophyta (Diatomeae) Zweite Auflage, Süsswass.-Fl. Mitteleurop. 10: 205 (1930). / Delikli sucıncığı.',
  6 => 'A. lineariformis Lange-Bert., Biblioth. Diatomol. 27: 7, 134 pl. (1993). / Düz sucıncığı.',
  7 => 'A. longipes C.Agardh, Syst. Alg.: 1 (1824). / Boylu sucıncığı.',
  8 => 'A. nollii Bock, Nachrichtendes Naturwiss. Museums Stadt Aschaffenburg 38: 1 (1953). / Yaban sucıncığı.',
  9 => 'A. parvula Kütz., Bacillarien: 76, pl. 21: ş. 5 (1844). / Saf sucıncığı.',
  10 => 'A. petersenii Hust., Rabenhorst’s Krypt.-Fl. Deutschl.: 179, ş 10-14 (1937). / Bal sucıncığı.',
  11 => 'A. pyrenaicum (Hust.) H.Kobayasi, Nova Hedwigia 65(1-4): 148, ş. 1-18 (1997). / Garip sucıncığı.',
  12 => 'A. stolida (Krasske) Krasske, Ann. Acad. Sc. Fenn., ser. A, Biol. 14: 78 (1949). / Alık sucıncığı.',
  13 => 'A. thermalis (Rabenh.) Schoenfeld, Diat. German.: 122 (1907). / Sıcak sucıncığı.',
  14 => 'A. trinodis (Ralfs) Grunow, Syn. Diatom. Belg.: pl. XXVII: ş. 50 (1880). / Üç sucıncığı.',
  15 => 'A. wellsiae Reimer, Monogr. Acad. Nat. Sci. Philadelphia 1: 16 (1966). / El sucıncığı.',
  16 => 'PLATESSA Lange-Bert., Süsswass.-Fl. Mitteleuropa 2: 443 (2004). / SUTANESİ.',
  17 => 'P. conspicua (Ant.Mayer) Lange-Bert., Süsswass.-Fl. Mitteleuropa 2: 445 (2004). / Küt sutanesi.',
  18 => 'P. montana (Krasske) Lange-Bert., Süsswass.-Fl. Mitteleuropa 2: 445 (2004). / Dağ sutanesi.',
  19 => 'P. salinarum (Grunow) Lange-Bert. / Sutanesi.',
  20 => 'ACHNANTHIDIUM Kütz., Bacillarien: 75 (1844). / SUÇUBUĞU.',
  21 => 'A. affine (Grunow) Czarn., Mem. Calif. Acad. Sci. 17: 156 (1994). / Hoş suçubuğu.',
  22 => 'A. deflexum Kingston, Diatom Res. 15(2): 409 (2000). / Kıvrık suçubuğu.',
  23 => 'A. exiguum (Grunow) Czarnecki, Mem. Calif. Acad. Sci. 17: 155 (1994). / Delikli suçubuğu.',
  24 => 'A. exile (Kütz.) Heiberg, Conspect. Diatom. Dan.: 119 (1863). / Bitik suçubuğu.',
  25 => 'A. lanceolatum (Bréb.) Kütz., Bot. Zeitung 4(14): 247 (1846). / Uzun suçubuğu.',
  26 => 'A. minutissimum (Kütz.) Czarn., Mem. Calif. Acad. Sci. 17: 155 (1994). / Cüce suçubuğu.',
  27 => 'A. minutum Cleve, Fl. Fenn. 8(2): 1 (1891). / Bodur suçubuğu.',
  28 => 'A. thermale Rabenh., Fl. Eur. Alg. 1: 107 (1864). / Sıcak suçubuğu.',
  29 => 'EUCOCCONEIS Cleve ex Meister, Beitr. Kryptogamenfl. Schweiz IV(1): 95 (1912). / SUESNEĞİ.',
  30 => 'E. flexella (Kütz.) Meister, Beitr. Kryptogamenfl. Schweiz IV(1): 95 (1912). / Suesneği.',
  31 => 'E. laevis (Østrup) Lange-Bert., Iconogr. Diatomol. 6: 46 (1999). / Pek suesneği.',
  32 => 'E. quadratarea (Østrup) Lange-Bert., Iconogr. Diatomol. 6: 48 (1999). / Dört suesneği.',
```

Comment: Are these strings individual array items to start? I.e., do you have something like `$species = ['ACHNANTHES', 'A. brevipes', 'A. coarctata', ...];`

Comment: yes, each line is an array index like [0], [1]...

Comment: Is this list ready sorted? Why not store it as a key value per such as `[ARCHANTHES => [ brevipes,...] ` and when you want to access them, strtolower the key and get the following value(s) for it

Comment: I don't know how to do it and it's a very long list like 4000 line

Comment: Please deliver, as an edit on your question, a small, realistic representation of your data -- in its truest array form.  Use `var_export()` and copy paste that text into your question. @Shraun

Comment: @Shraun to deliver you the most effective and direct solution, we will need to see how your data is generated at the earliest point in your project.  If this is coming from a file, what kind of file is it and how is the data formatted? if from a database, show us the result set.  If it starts as text, then you break it into array elements by exploding on newlines, then this is unnecessary extra work because it looks like you have a desired result that is a single string of text again.  We need super clear details from you.  I am happy to help once the question is fixed up.

Comment: i added it to my question

Comment: @Shraun I can work with that array, but where does that array come from? and what exact output do you want? Do you want to keep the array structure or generate a single block of text / string that will use newlines to separate.  I don't want to waste any time providing something that you don't want.  I want to process this from its rawest form and generate the EXACT desired output.  How are you using this data after this step?  Just displaying it to screen?  Storing it in a file?  Generating html content with it?  I have upvoted your question, but I still want more -- it'd be worth it.

Comment: i will push each line as a row to sql database

Comment: I would like to see the prepared statement that you plan to implement.  Because if I don't see the columns that you are going to be inserting data into, I could end up doing unnecessary work.  Please show me the schema that you are going to push data into.  Are you using pdo or mysqli?  The site is asking me to start a chat room, but I have no time or interest in doing this.  Please edit your question to provide all of my requested details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am a little disappointed that I don't have enough details to get you all the way to the querying process, so I'll just mutate your element values.

1. Establish a grouping string -- the Genus variable.  Set it to null before entering the loop
2. As you iterate, determine if the current row is a genus value by extracting the first word, then checking if it is comprised exclusively of uppercase letters.

   - if so, cache it as the new grouping value and store it to the output array
   - if not, then push the formatted "Genus species" string into the results array

I love regex, but because your data is already split into elements, there is no benefit to using regex for this task.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/V8uAE))

```
$result = [];
$currentGenus = null;
foreach ($array as $line) {
    $firstWord = strstr($line, ' ', true);
    if (ctype_upper($firstWord)) {
        $currentGenus = $firstWord;
        $result[] = $firstWord;
    } else {
        $result[] = ucfirst(strtolower($currentGenus)) . ' ' . explode(' ', $line, 3)[1];
    }
}
var_export($result);
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => 'ACHNANTHES',
  1 => 'Achnanthes brevipes',
  2 => 'Achnanthes coarctata',
  3 => 'Achnanthes cocconeiformis',
  4 => 'Achnanthes gibberula',
  5 => 'Achnanthes lacunarum',
  6 => 'Achnanthes lineariformis',
  7 => 'Achnanthes longipes',
  8 => 'Achnanthes nollii',
  9 => 'Achnanthes parvula',
  10 => 'Achnanthes petersenii',
  11 => 'Achnanthes pyrenaicum',
  12 => 'Achnanthes stolida',
  13 => 'Achnanthes thermalis',
  14 => 'Achnanthes trinodis',
  15 => 'Achnanthes wellsiae',
  16 => 'PLATESSA',
  17 => 'Platessa conspicua',
  18 => 'Platessa montana',
  19 => 'Platessa salinarum',
  20 => 'ACHNANTHIDIUM',
  21 => 'Achnanthidium affine',
  22 => 'Achnanthidium deflexum',
  23 => 'Achnanthidium exiguum',
  24 => 'Achnanthidium exile',
  25 => 'Achnanthidium lanceolatum',
  26 => 'Achnanthidium minutissimum',
  27 => 'Achnanthidium minutum',
  28 => 'Achnanthidium thermale',
  29 => 'EUCOCCONEIS',
  30 => 'Eucocconeis flexella',
  31 => 'Eucocconeis laevis',
  32 => 'Eucocconeis quadratarea',
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would be pleased to be proven wrong but I don't think the desired result can be obtain with the PCRE regex engine, using simple substitutions.

Suppose the string were

```
ACHNANTHES
A. brevipes
A. coarctata
A. cocconeiformis
PLATESSA
P. conspicua
P. montana
P. salinarum
```

If you reversed the lines to obtain

```
P. salinarum
P. montana
P. conspicua
PLATESSA
A. cocconeiformis
A. coarctata
A. brevipes
ACHNANTHES
```

you could use the regex

```
^[A-Z]\.(?=\s+[a-z]+\s*(?:[A-Z]\.\s+[a-z]+\s*)*([A-Z]+)\s*$)
```

to obtain matches and replace each with the contents of the capture group, to obtain

```
PLATESSA salinarum
PLATESSA montana
PLATESSA conspicua
PLATESSA
ACHNANTHES cocconeiformis
ACHNANTHES coarctata
ACHNANTHES brevipes
ACHNANTHES
```

at which point the desired result is obtained by reversing those lines:

```
ACHNANTHES
ACHNANTHES brevipes
ACHNANTHES coarctata
ACHNANTHES cocconeiformis
PLATESSA
PLATESSA conspicua
PLATESSA montana
PLATESSA salinarum
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/hTx9gN/2/)

The following operations are performed by PHP's regex engine, PCRE.

```
^                # match beginning of line
[A-Z]\.          # match uc ltr then '.' 
(?=              # begin non-cap grp
  \s+[a-z]+\s*   # match 1+ whtspaces, 1+ lc ltrs, 0+ whtspaces
  (?:            # begin non-cap grp
    [A-Z]\.      # match line begin with uc ltr then '.'
    \s+[a-z]+\s* # match 1+ whtspaces, 1+ lc ltrs, 0+ whtspaces 
  )              # end non-cap grp
  *              # execute non-cap grp 0+ times
  ([A-Z]+)       # match 1+ uc ltrs in cap grp 1
  \s*            # match 0+ whtspaces
  $              # match end of line
)                # end positive lookahead
```

Comment: I believe I might be able to prove you wrong, but I'll wait until the OP updates the question with a more accurate representation of the input and the exact desired output.

Comment: @mickmackusa, I hope you do (truly). Your handle is an odd one for an Aussie.

Comment: ...must be dyslexia

Answer (score 0):

To solve your problem, I would first think about what kind of logic you are going to use before you think about any PHP language specifics. Most general purpose programming languages (such as PHP) can do most anything you would need in regards to string manipulation, so don't worry about how you are going to implement your logic right now.

I think using a regex library would be overkill in this situation. There are a lot of ways to solve your problem, and there's usually a better one than what first pops into my mind, but I'll go over the logic of what first popped into my mind.

First, I am going to go over some important assumptions. It was implied that genus rows only contain letters, and species rows will start with a letter, then a dot. I also assume three new things:

1. There are no other types of rows than genus rows and species rows
2. Genus rows are at least two characters long
3. The very first line is a genus name.

All these assumptions should be true, and if they are, then this solution will work. Here is my logic in English:

```
Declare a variable that will be a string that keeps track of your current genus name 

For each line (AKA for each string in your array), do this chunk of code:
  See if the second letter of the current line is not a dot
    If it is not, this line is your current genus name: change
      your current genus name variable to the current line
  BUT... if the second letter of the current line IS a dot
    This is a species line, and we will need to transform it, and to do that...
    Make a new string that is the current line with the first two characters cut off
    Make a new string copy of your current genus name, but where it just 
      starts with a capital instead of being all-caps
    Make a new string, which is those two strings you just made put together
    Replace the current line with that newest string you just made
```

Now, I'm not going to give you an outright solution, because Stack Overflow will hate me if I deprive you of this learning opportunity, but I will let you know some useful syntax on how to solve this problem.

**foreach loops** https://www.w3schools.in/php/looping/foreach/

**strings** https://www.php.net/language.types.string (search for 'String access and modification by character')

**if and else statements** https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_if_else.asp

**substring** https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php

**useful string-case functions** https://www.javatpoint.com/php-string-strtolower-function

**string concatenation** https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php

P.S. - a truly good solution will have error handling, like what to do in the event that there is a genus name that is only one character long, or having lines that are only return characters, etc, but for simplicity's sake, I didn't do that in this solution. This answer should work for your purposes, just keep in mind that error handling is good practice and will save you a lot of headache down the road.